# не работает smtplib python

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib

код такой:

```py
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtplib.gmail.com", 587)
```

и вот коды ошибок

```
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\code.py", line 6, in send_mail
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtplib.gmail.com")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 822, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменяйте адрес на smtp.gmail.com